# Is it working to use a native image of a dll that has been deleted?

Tags: c#, ngen

Assuming that a native image was generated (with ngen) for a .NET dll.
After that this dll is deleted.
If I would now run a program that uses this dll, would it work?

Comment: maybe? But it is really not something I would rely on. Deployment is difficult enough, without introducing weird edge-cases.

Comment: No, the CLR will only use the ngen image when the regular assembly gets loaded.  Since it is missing, the program will crash.  Easy to check this yourself btw.